# Windows 10 IOT core wont boot

Tags: raspberry-pi3, windows-10-iot-core

I got older RPI3 that works like a charm. I bought new RPI 3B+ new SandDisk class 10 SD Card and installed W10 IoT Core. I am stuck on boot screen (that colorful one) and cannot pass it.

Power supply is industrial 5V/20A supply. It must be enough for 2 RPIs.
SD card is good. I tried it in older RPI, booted immediately.

Comment: How did you install the image on Raspberry Pi3B+? Did you download the image from this [link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsiot) and then install this custom image with IoT Dashboard?

Comment: Ive put SD card into PC and direct install it from IoT Dashboard. I installed latest (17763) version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently Raspberry Pi 3B+ is a technical preview and there is no timeline for a release version. Limited validation and enablement has been completed. You need to download the image from this link(https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsiot). And then use IoT Dashboard to flush the image(*.ffu). In IoT Dashboard, please change OS Build to **Custom**, and then browse the ffu file to flush.

[image]

Comment: Great answer. I did not know that RPI3B+ is something "special"